# How to make some of my web pages searchable in my project

Tags: search-engine, blogs

In my website i am including user to add blogs. How can i make those blogs searchable in google. I want to make only the blogs searchable. But i don't want to make remaining pages searchable. How can i do this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

On all pages **except** the blog pages, add the following to your HTML `<head>` element:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

This will prevent search engines from indexing the page.

---

Using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)/[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) isn't an option as this is client scripting, which the bots won't read.

Comment: How can i add the only blog pages to search in google. I mean what is the procedure

Comment: @karthik Google will either naturally pick up your site via links from other sites. Or you can submit the URL on google for them to start indexing it. With `noindex` in the meta data, Google will know **not** to index the pages with that on.

Comment: @karthik It's kind of the reverse of what you are asking. You don't tell Google which pages to index, you tell them which pages not to index.